# is it possible to integrate word to access 2007

Tags: windows, microsoft-word-2007, microsoft-access-2007

I'm wondering if it's possible to integrate word 2007 to access 2007.
I downloaded this template "Customer Service Support" from the Microsoft site and one table of this database represent "Knowledge Base" now I'm thinking to write the Topic in Access and the solution I will provide a link, and this link should open the word file which is saved in our server.
Do you think this is possible?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this [Tech on the net article](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/modules/word_doc.php) there's code that will launch a file from the local disk:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()

    Dim LWordDoc As String
    Dim oApp As Object

    'Path to the word document
    LWordDoc = "c:\Doc1.doc"

    If Dir(LWordDoc) = "" Then
        MsgBox "Document not found."

    Else
        'Create an instance of MS Word
        Set oApp = CreateObject(Class:="Word.Application")
        oApp.Visible = True

        'Open the Document
        oApp.Documents.Open filename:=LWordDoc
    End If

End Sub
```

This should work if you replace "c:\Doc1.doc" with "\server\folder\doc1.doc"

While the article doesn't mention newer versions of Access/Word this should still work.